# GPPSignIn not calling openURL:sourceApplication method in the appDelegate after returns

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-plus

I am using the `Google plus Framework` in my app, but I can't get the `response` when I get back from the `Google-Plu`s app. I have added the `URL-Scheme`, I have the same bundle in the console and in the app. I also have the correct `CLIENTID`. 
Anyone has the same problem??

Could be possible that the problem happen in `iOS 8` or `Xcode 6`??

Now, I am getting this error:

```
Error Domain=com.google.GooglePlusPlatform Code=-1 "keychain error" UserInfo=0x175263ec0 {NSLocalizedDescription=keychain error}
```

Thank you

Comment: what are you getting in console? what kind of error. ? anything ?

Comment: Nothing, when I call  `[signIn authenticate];` GPlus app is opened, then I authorise my app in google plus. and then GPlus app goes to background and my app appears again. But `openURL:sourceApplication...` is never called